# Angular UI grid - unable to mask pagination controls

Tags: css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using Angular-Bootstrap UI grid. I want to create a spinner and mask the grid when the data is loading. I have used http://plnkr.co/edit/Eq1OT49NJEGQ6wTs389K?p=preview to create my spinner. But the problem is when I use pagination the mask used does not mask the pagination controls. Please refer to the snapshot. How can I achieve a mask over pagination controls?

I have added following controls to app.js file

```
 vm.gridOptions.paginationPageSizes= [5,10,15];
 vm.gridOptions.paginationPageSize= 5;
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply hide the pagination controls by setting `enablePaginationControls = false` when data is loading or there is no data.
This can be easily achieved by setting a watch over your vm.loading and whenever it changes, change the gridOptions settings.

See [plunkr example](http://plnkr.co/edit/MGmXFXYbVlVaEarJUDpp?p=preview)

By the way, [Angular UI Grid](http://ui-grid.info/) is not part of bootstrap framework, it's part of the [AngularUI Suite](http://angular-ui.github.io/).